# How to .querySelectAll() from .getElementsByTagNAme() html element?

Tags: javascript, html

Let suppose I have HTML like:

```
 <html>

 <body>
     <ul>
         <li>list</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
     </ul>
     <div>div</div>
     <p>something else</p>
 </body>

 </html>
```

and I want to get all UL elements:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
```

Now I would like to get all list elements:

```
var allListElements = ul.querySelectorAll("ul > li");
```

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var allListElements = ul.querySelectorAll("ul > li");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div>div</div>
<p>something else</p>
```

However this is not working... but `getElementById` is working fine with `querySelectAll()`. So how to make to work HTMLcollection or NodeList with `querySelectorAll()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `querySelectorAll` with the `ul > li` query string alone, on the `document`:

```js
var allListElements = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");
console.log(allListElements);
```

```html
<ul>
<li>list</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<div>div</div>
<p>something else</p>
```

If you already have an HTMLCollection that you need to effectively call `querySelectorAll` on, it'd be more complicated, you'd have to call `querySelectorAll` on each element in the HTMLCollection:

```js
var uls = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var allListElements = [...uls].reduce((a, ul) => {
  a.push(...ul.querySelectorAll('li'));
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(allListElements);
```

```html
<ul>
<li>list</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<div>div</div>
<p>something else</p>
```

Comment: Hi. "Just call querySelectorAll with the ul > li query string alone, on the document" I can't there are more lements and I don't know what number my UL has (random). I will try second example, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things to keep in mind:

1. [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object.
2. You must call `Element` query methods from an specific DOM node.

Your last JS line needs two changes:

1. First, you need to select the specific DOM node from the `ul` collection. Ex: `ul[0]`
2. Since you are querying the DOM from to the `<ul>` node you must exclude this element from the query. Ex: `ul[0].querySelectorAll("li")`

Please find the final edits below:

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var allListElements = ul[0].querySelectorAll("li");

console.log(allListElements)
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<ul>
<li>list</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<div>div</div>
<p>something else</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Your are right by giving the "ul[0]" elemnet position. But in my case there are more UL elements and I don;t know the element number I want to get (random)... so I need to get them all (from  PART of the document - not tho whole document - cause it is very big). Thanks.

Comment: @yasiDrovi You can apply the same concept as well. For example, if you have a `#sidebar` div, you can first get the DOM reference or scope `sidebar document.getElementById('sidebar')` then get `<li>` elements `sidebar.querySelectorAll('ul > li')`

Comment: Pable and this is exactly what is not working for me :) That is why I ask here for possible solution. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have all the information you need. Have fun figuring it out 

Comment: Yes you are right :) I did resolve my problem by iterating through NodeList object and combine every i.innerHTML (to get HTML content) to variable that I pass later on. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The `ul > li` elements are not contained inside the `ul` - they're on the `document`. Use that query string:

```js
var allListElements = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")];
console.log(allListElements);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<div>div</div>
<p>something else</p>
```